# Manchester - Doha - Bali

Tags: doha, connecting-flights

We are travelling to Bali via Doha from UK. Connection to Doha is only 55m. I am guessing because we booked it on the same ticket it should be enough to make the connection? We alre flying with Quatar airlines. Also do we need a visa to be able to make a connection in Doha? My nationality is Lithuaniain. Return connection is in Doha as well but its 50min.

Answer (score 5):

The minimum connecting time (MCT) between Qatar Airways flights in Doha is 45 minutes (60 minutes for flights to the United States), as this allows sufficient time for your transfer as well as for the transfer of your baggage to your onward connecting flight.

http://support.qatarairways.com/hc/en-us/articles/206466698-I-have-a-short-connection-is-this-enough-time-to-make-my-connecting-flight-

You should be fine, in the worst case they put you on next flight for free.